# Nuxt.js: Find Client Viewport Size and Generate Content

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, vega-lite

I've built an app on Nuxt. Part of the app uses data visualization technologies such as D3 and Vega. I'm finding that Vega and D3 are tricky in Nuxt.

My biggest issue is: how can I find the client's viewport size and generate my visualizations based on that? That's typically how I'd do it in plain JavaScript.

For instance, I would do this:

```
const vw = Math.min(Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0), 900) 
const ratio = 1.52

      var yourVlSpec = {
        $schema: 'https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.0.json',
        description: 'A simple bar chart with embedded data.',
        data: {
          values: [
            {a: 'A', b: 28},
            {a: 'B', b: 55},
            {a: 'C', b: 43},
            {a: 'D', b: 91},
            {a: 'E', b: 81},
            {a: 'F', b: 53},
            {a: 'G', b: 19},
            {a: 'H', b: 87},
            {a: 'I', b: 52}
          ]
        },
        width: vw,
        height: vw / ratio,
        mark: 'bar',
        encoding: {
          x: {field: 'a', type: 'ordinal'},
          y: {field: 'b', type: 'quantitative'}
        }
      };
      vegaEmbed('#vis', yourVlSpec);
```

How would I get the client viewport dimensions in Nuxt? And what other things do I need to do to be able to pull this off given that Nuxt uses SSR by default?

Comment: You can do this calculation in a lifecycle hook that only runs in the browser, i.e. `mounted`.

Comment: If I do that, then how do I pass it over to my data? For instance, I do:    

 mounted(){
    const vw = Math.min(Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0), 900)
  }
}

How can I pass "vw" over to the data in the .vue file?

Comment: Initialize vw in data property assign Number to it and in mounted `this.vw = your logic`